# How can I disable csrutil when recovery mode gives a prohibitory icon?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to install psycopg2 so that I can link Python applications into PostgreSQL. The installation is failing and so I need to implement a fix. However, the commands I need to run for the fix fail. This is where I need help.

The fix for the first fix failing (allegedly) is to disable csrutil from Recovery Mode on mac. When I go into networked recovery mode (cmd-option-R), csrutil is not a recognized program. When I go into normal recovery mode (cmd-R), I get a "prohibitory icon".

These are the commands that fail, requiring me to disable csrutil.

```
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
```

Comment: This question would be better asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).  Have you tried putting the symlinks in /usr/local/lib instead?  csrutil will let you do that and it *should* get them picked up by whichever software needs them (it may also be necessary to do something similar involving /usr/include versus /usr/local/include).

Comment: Thanks zwol! This actually fixed this problem.